# Xcode compile fails on internal error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having issues compiling a previously working xcode project. All it says is that there is an internal error. I have tried cleaning the project and the build files. The error is listed below. Any idea of how to fix this? I have tried both xcode 7.2 and 7.2.1.

Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/tc/_8l_rs9n055_0zqdny0k89nr0000gp/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-03-01_09-46-22_280000".

The error it shows I am getting is below. How do I find what view it is referring to? 
Exception name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Exception reason: Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|[self]

Comment: You should post the contents of /var/folders/tc/_8l_rs9n055_0zqdny0k89nr0000gp/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-03-01_09-46-22_280000.  That's the only way to get more information. Try opening a Terminal Window and entering the command: `cp /var/folders/tc/_8l_rs9n055_0zqdny0k89nr0000gp/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-03-01_09-46-22_280000 ~/Desktop/diag.txt`  It will show on your Desktop as `diag.txt` and will open up in TextEdit.

Comment: The error is related to auto layout. One of the constraints has an invalid format

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using visual constraint language to constrain views.

The error says

> Unable to parse constraint format: Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview H:|[self]

which means that you are applying those constraints before you have actually added the view to its superview (the constraint tries to refer to the superview edge (the pipe `|` symbol)) which is not present because the view you are trying to apply constraints to has not yet been added to its superview.

So here is a scenario that could cause the issue:

```
let view = UIView()
let subview = UIView()
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[v]|"))
```

And how to solve it:

```
let view = UIView()
let subview = UIView()
view.addSubview(subview) // you have to add it to the superview before applying constraints
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[v]|"))
```